# circuitikz pnp transistor; control sequence undefined

Tags: circuitikz

I'm using the `Circuitikz` package to draw a circuit which has a pnp transistor. The editor I use is TexStudio. It gives me the following error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   
> \pgf@sh@bg@pnp -> \pgftransformationadjustments 
>                                                   
> \pgfsetcolor {\pgfkeysvalueo...
>   
> l.10        ;
>   
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
>   of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
>   misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
>   spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
>   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

I created a MWE. If I compile the empty document, and then with the drawing of the pnp transistor, it still compiles, draws the transistor, and gives me the error. When I don't compile it beforehand (so there's no preview open) and then try to compile with the drawing of the pnp transistor, it gives me the error and doesn't compile.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
            (0,0) node [pnp] {node}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Also, the following (which is just a node, not a pnp transistor) works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
            (0,0) node {node}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

I don't see why it gives me the error, I did what was in the `Circuitikz`  [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf)  (page 22). All code from other people on the internet, and examples I find, is the same, so that didn't get me any further, either.

**EDIT**

I added something to the code, which now is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
            (0,0) node [pnp] {node}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't complain about the semicolon anymore, but now I have these errors instead:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   
>  ...pgfverticaltransformationadjustment 
>                                                     
> *.5*\pgflinewidth 
>   
> l.11            (
>           
>  pnp.B) to (-2,0)
>   
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
>   of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
>   misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
>   spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
>   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>   
>  
>                    
>   p
>   
> l.11            (
>       
>      pnp.B) to (-2,0)
>   
> A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
>   (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
>   look up`weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me.    Make sure your packages are up to date and you are running PDFlatex (also called Latex->PDF).

Comment: Just checked. I am using PDFlatex. According to MiKTeX I installed the circuitikz pagacke on 2016-07-09, and it was packaged on 2016-06-07. So that should be right, I suppose. Could it be that any other of my packages is outdated and that that causes the trouble?

Comment: Is TikZ up to date?

Comment: Alright, I'm now running an MiKTeX Update as admin. First only saw the Package Manager...

Comment: Yes, running that update worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an answer to my own question to close off the question, and maybe help other people in the future.

As mentioned in the comments by  [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo):

> Make sure your packages are up to date.

I did this by going to the MiKTeX Update (Admin) and simply updating the packages. That did the trick.